# AX2012: how to get all project names from the database?

Tags: axapta, x++

I want an overview over all (shared) projects of all Applications.

I could write a job using infolog.projectRootNode(),
but I have to execute this job (periodically) on every AOS.

Therefore I would prefer to extract the data directly from the database (application or model).
But I cannot find a table that contains these data.

Where is this information stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execute next SQL on *_Model* database.

```sql
SELECT Name
FROM [ModelElement]
WHERE ElementType=37
ORDER BY Name
```